# sqlite3 preparing, binding and resetting statements

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

Can someone put more light on the functions:

```
sqlite3_reset();
sqlite3_clear_bindings()
```

I understand that I can use **sqlite3_prepare()** to translate sql string to native byte code which engine understands. Therefor the engine does not have to translate it every time when it is used. I can also parametrize such prepared statement and later bind values to it with **sqlite3_bind*()** functions.

I can assign NULL value to these binded params with sqlite3_clear_bindings().
From [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) one can read that sqlite3_reset(), does not destroy bindings, the values are preserved and the object is put into initial state. What does it actually mean?
Especially the part about not destroying bindings.

Comment: Is it correct that when you bind, then the values are copied to the stmt? (besides the sqlite3_bind_text*() functions where you have to specify 5th param).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite3_reset` clears the state that the prepared statement maintained during execution.  This sets it back to the initial state, thus "resetting it".  Bindings remain intact.  The statement can be re-executed.  Without resetting it, you will receive an error when you try to execute it.

`sqlite3_clear_bindings` will just clear the bindings, but not change the state on the prepared statement.  You can't re-execute a prepared statement if you just cleared the bindings.